# Integrate Paperjs Voronoi in Requirejs

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, paperjs

I tried to integrate Paperjs in Requirejs to generate Vornoi pattern. Able to load Paperjs library in requirejs. Reference: http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/

Structure of the requirejs: Application(config.js,image.html,main.js, voronoi.js) Lib(paper.js, rhill-voronoi-core.min.js)

I added only html part in image.html and paper script in voronoi.js. Loaded paperjs and rhill-voronoi-core.min.js in vornoi.js file and created paperscope to access canvas like this:

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

paper.setup(canvas);

var view = paper.view;

Here I am facing issue while performing division on   view.size(like:view.size/200)  result is NaN. But if I add paperscript in HTML page then there is no issue.

How to solve this? I wanted to make script separate as requirejs follows.